# Skipping node client's intermediate versions

Tags: runtime-upgrade, upgrade

The substrate node consists of 2 parts: [runtime and outer node (or node client)](https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/architecture/).

The Substrate has [forkless upgrade](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/forkless-upgrade/) functionality for the runtime updates. Sometimes [node client should be updated first](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-runtime-upgrades#new-client-releases) to support the next runtime version. Usually, it is because of new host functions. [Example](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.0).

Having the fact that the node client should be able to sync from the scratch (it means that it should be compatible with any runtime version), am I correct that if I need to update the node client and node runtime from [0.9.0](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.0) to [0.9.16](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.16) I can update node client to the latest version 0.9.16 and apply all node runtimes (from 0.9.1 to 0.9.16) skipping intermediate node client updates? Or node client has some data migrations (or something similar) under the hood so it is better not to skip versions and apply node client updates one by one?